# Leader key for many commands

Tags: vimrc

Many commands need the `Leader` key, but I can't found out what is that key on my keyboard. How could I test it out?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't set one, the default leader is the backslash `\`

You can set your leader with `:let mapleader = "x"`, for example to make x your leader.

It's handy to set this at the top of your .vimrc to whatever your desired leader is (I use space as mine). See `:h leader` for more info and examples.